# SQLite - where clause not work with two columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

In sqlite I has query:

```
select * FROM notification_invoice where (notificationDate, ownerKey) IN (
  select distinct notificationDate, ownerKey FROM notification_invoice where providerId in ("12345","6789") 
)
```

But I get error:

```
Error: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near ",": syntax error)
SQLState:  null
ErrorCode: 1
```

Comment: you can pass only one value to  compare with one value in  'IN' operator

select * FROM notification_invoice where (notificationDate) IN (
  select distinct notificationDate FROM notification_invoice where providerId in ("12345","6789") 
) or (ownerKey) IN (
  select distinct ownerKey FROM notification_invoice where providerId in ("12345","6789") 
)

Comment: why not you are using 'and' between two column's value comparison in where clause!

Comment: Are you using a really old version of sqlite?

Comment: I use sqlite-jdbc-3.8.10.1.jar

Answer (score 2):

I don't think SQLite supports tuples with `in`.  Just use `exists`:

```
select ni.* 
from notification_invoice ni
where exists (select 1
              from notification_invoice ni2
              where ni2.notificationDate = ni.notificationDate and
                    ni2.ownerKey and ni.ownerKey and
                    ni2.providerId in ('12345', '6789') 
             );
```

Comment: Sqlite does support [row values](https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html)... I'm thinking OP is using an old version that predates that support, though.